# Python Sympy subs() no sustituye una variable modificada por su nueva versión

Tags: python, sympy

Uso Python 3.5. Voy a poner un ejemplo muy simplificado de mi caso:

```
from sympy import *
a,b = symbols('a,b')
lon = symbols(r'\epsilon')
print("Antiguo lon=",lon)

a = b+sqrt(b)
a = a.subs(b,lon)
print("Antigua a=",a,"\n")

# Hasta aqui todo bien

lon = 1+lon**3
print("Nuevo lon=",lon)

# Aqui bien tambien, "lon" se actualiza

a = a.subs(lon,lon)
print("Nueva a=",a)

# Aqui es donde se ve el problema: no actualiza "a" con el nuevo "lon"
# incluso pidendolo expresamente con ".subs()"
```

Es decir, me interesa poder crear expresiones y si en alguna de sus variables hago cambios, poder meter los cambios después en dichas expresiones y de este modo actualizarlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que no cambie, es que la expresión `lon` no existe en la expresión `a` en ese punto y aunque existiera se substituiría por si misma.

Cundo haces `lon = 1+lon**3` **reasignas al identificador `lon`** la expresión `lon = 1+lon**3`, de forma que `lon` a partir de ahora ya no es una instancia de `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol` sino de `sympy.core.add.Add` en este caso concreto.

Lo anterior causa que cuando aplicas `sub` sobre `a` (`sqrt(epsilon) + epsilon`) intente substituir `\epsilon**3 + 1` por si mismo, por lo que la salida es la expresión `a` sin modificar, para empezar `\epsilon**3 + 1` ni existe en `a`, y de existir seria substituirse por si mismo.

No sobreescribas el símbolo o expresión a substituir antes de aplicar `sub`:

```
>>> ex = 1 + lon**3
>>> a.subs(lon, ex)
\epsilon**3 + sqrt(\epsilon**3 + 1) + 1
```

---

En Python (y SymPy por tanto) las variables no se definen automáticamente,  han  de ser definidas de forma explícita,  además deben ser siempre inicializadas,  es decir,  siempre deben apuntalar a la referencia de un objeto en memoria.

Como en SymPy, como módulo para la manipulación simbólica que es,  necesita 
poder usar variables simbólicas se usa la clase `Symbol` para representarlas:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> x = Symbols ('x')
>>> expresion = x ** 2
>>> expresion.subs(x,  4)
16
```

Por norma general es recomendable que  el nombre de un símbolo y el nombre de la variable Python a la que está asignado coincidan para evitar confusiones. La única excepción debería ser cuando el símbolo no sea un nombre válido en Python.

Hay que tener muy clara la diferencia entre `SymPy.Symbols` y las variables de Python. En el ejemplo anterior `x` es una variable Python,  un identificador que está asociado a la referencia de un objeto en memoria concreto,  en este caso está asociado a una instancia de `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol` usada para expresar una variable simbólica `"x"`:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> x = symbols ('x')
>>> x = x ** 2
```

En este caso, con `x = x ** 2` reasignamos la variable Python `x` que haora apunta a la expresión `x ** 2`, eso no implica que la instancia `Symbol("x")` anterior sea modificada. Para verlo más claro:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> x = simbols ('x')
>>> expresion = x + 13
>>> x = 7
>>> print(expr)
x + 13
>>> print(x)
7
```

Reasignar un nuevo valor a `x` (el entero 7) no tuvo efecto en `expresion`. Cuando creamos `expresion`, la variable de Python `x` era un "símbolo", después de  cambiar la variable de Python `x` a 7, pero `expresion` no va a cambiar por eso, en su construcción se usó la instancia a la que antes apuntaba la variable Python `x` (`Symbol("x")`) y se va a seguir usando la misma aunque reasignemos otra cosa a la variable Python `x` después. Esto hay que tenerlo presente siempre en Python, **las variables son solo identificadores o nombres que apuntan a referencias de objetos en memoria** en un momento cocntreto, ni más ni menos.

Comment: Efectivamente, veo que es una cuestión de cómo se guarda en memoria todo (etiqueta o nombre, valor, tipo, posición). Por así decirlo, python-sympy no te "intenta entender" hasta tan lejos por el momento. La solución al problema es crear una variable auxiliar que recoja los cambios que quieres meter. Por ejemplo, hacer "nlon=1+lon**3" y ya después "a=a.subs(lon,nlon)". Lección aprendida: tener variable auxiliar para meter los cambios. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En realidad si no la necesitas no tienes porque crear una variable que haga referencia a la expresión, puedes hacer simplemente `a.subs(lon, 1 + lon**3)` lo que sustituirá todos los símbolos `\epsilon` de la expresión por `1 + lon**3`.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla, tienes razón para este ejemplo no haría falta crear una auxiliar. En mi caso "real" (no este) la creo de todos modos porque es más largo, voy haciendo cambios y llego a un resultado final tras varios pasos. No crear la variable me supondría una asignación muy larga o incluso no realizable. Pero en efecto, para este ejemplo, no haría falta, se puede hacer directamente como propones. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Mi código previo redefinía las cosas, implicando destrucción y creación de variables. Lo seguro es crear una variable auxiliar que recoja los cambios.

He marcado como respuesta correcta la de @FJSevilla porque es quien me ha encaminado hacia la solución. No obstante, la solución a mi ejemplo es esta:

```
from sympy import *
a,b = symbols('a,b')
lon = symbols(r'\epsilon')
print("Antiguo lon=",lon)

a = b+sqrt(b)
a = a.subs(b,lon)
print("Antigua a=",a,"\n")

# Hasta aqui todo bien

nlon = 1+lon**3
print("'nlon' que es el nuevo lon, nlon=",nlon)

# Aqui bien tambien, "nlon" se crea con lo que quiero meter

a = a.subs(lon,nlon)
print("Nueva a=",a)

# Ahora ya funciona. Creo "nlon" para recoger los cambios que deseo.
```